# Only Malloc Lower 32bit address

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, malloc

I've got a question on malloc in 64 bit machine. 
I was wondering if it is possible for malloc to only allocate memory from lower 32bit addr. For instance, only allocate memory from 0xcfffffff to 0xffffffff, as it is in the 32bit machine.

Thanks for the help.

---

Update:
At the moment, I am trying to implement a memory management tool for GPU devices which uses OpenCL.
In order to do that, I need to intercept memory creating APIs from OpenCL, and reimplement them on my own. In other words, I implement a virtual memory for GPU devices on the host side. The problem is, in NVIDIA cuda, the OpenCL only has 32bit memory ptrs even in 64 bit machine. Therefore, every time I malloc a memory on the host side and tried to treat it as a OpenCL memory, the higher 32 bit will be truncated. Therefore, if I could malloc only lower 32bit, then there would be no problem.

Comment: Wouldn't it just be easier to fix your program to stop truncating pointers?

Comment: There *might* be some system-specific way to do this. C in general has no such mechanism. Why do you need to do this?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Surely the GPU has its own memory that is quite distinct from that of the main machine. In other words, `malloc` will get you memory that can be accessed on the main machine, but not on the GPU.

Comment: Then your question is how to allocate GPU memory, *not* how to use `malloc` to allocate GPU memory.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to create your own memory allocator. The starting point would be to use operating system services (system dependent) to allocate pages in the lower 32-bit range. Then use your functions to allocate memory from those pages.

Comment: Yup, I realized that specific solution. Then it is actually very hard for me to apply this tool in many scenarios due to it requires a unique sys call. Thx

Comment: You could encapsulate the system specific stuff.

Answer (score 0):

No.

`malloc()` is not under your control to allocate the memory from where you need. It is done internally by `malloc()` by using the size passed as a parameter.

Comment: is it possible to use mmap rather malloc?

Comment: @Giorgio You need to tell why exactly you need this how does it matter to you where memory gets allocated?